# setVisibility(View.GONE) is not working! Why?

Tags: java, android, xml

This code was working on my previous app that I was working on, but now it wont do anything at all, It should be a simple thing I must have forgot before using this code but I don't know what it was.

What I am trying to accomplish is to make the button gone and make the layout visible.

Here is my xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E675E8">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/natlilandbarpic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/drawbtn"
            android:id="@+id/drawbutton"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1.0">

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Text"
            android:id="@+id/webView"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/drawlist">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {
        private WebView webView;
        private Button drawbutton;
        private LinearLayout drawlist;
        
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            getActionBar().hide();
            
            
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("");
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
                
        public void addListenerOnButton() {
            
            drawbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.drawbutton);
            drawbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View p) {   
                    drawbuttonprop(p);
                    }
                });
            drawlist = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawlist);
        }
        public void drawbuttonprop(View view)
        {
            drawbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            drawlist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

}
```

Comment: You never call your `addListenerOnButton()` method, so `drawbutton` and `drawlist` are never assigned, and the `OnClickListener` is never set.

Comment: so drawbuttonprop wont work?

Comment: what is the right way to assign them then?

Comment: The only place you call `drawbuttonprop()` is from the `OnClickListener` you set in `addListenerOnButton()`. You're not calling `addListenerOnButton()` currently, though, so that never gets set. I'm not sure what you mean by "the right way", but if you simply call your `addListenerOnButton()` from `onCreate()`, after `setContentView()`, then what you have should work, assuming that's the correct, current layout.

Comment: oh my god I knew I forgot smthing tnx man it was driving me crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of All I guess the reason why you re experiencing that because you are not calling the function `addListenerOnButton()`, so you have to call it in your oncreate, secondly you are calling the function which also sets the drawlist visibility to visible after the button is clicked but you have to be aware that you are trying to find the reference of the drawlist after clicking the button and that will cause the app to crash, so you need to put this line of code `drawlist = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawlist);` along with first findViewById of the button